# Выход с помощью клавиш из окна tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Объясните, пожалуйста, на простом примере, как закрыть окно tkinter, например, нажав сочетание клавиш shift+ctrl.

Comment: Что из документации по этому поводу вы прочитали, и что конкретно вызывает у вас затруднения?

Comment: @СергейКох, у меня вызвало затруднение то, как назначить клавишу, которая будет отвечать за закрытие окна tkinter. Понятно, что можно через библиотеку keyboard, но мне нужно именно через tkinter.

Comment: Вам непонятно как ловить событие, или как его обрабатывать или как закрыть окно?

Comment: Почитайте <https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/concepts.html#:~:text=some%20other%20procedure.-,Binding%20to%20Events,-For%20events%20that>

Comment: @СергейКох, мне не понятно как ловить событие, и как его обрабатывать.

Comment: И следующий параграф там, как захватить две клавиши.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрал, понял.